# iOS Post to Facebook wall mention tag user

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to make a post from my iOS app with a mention to some friends. I got his "id".

So i use the follow and isn't work:

```
        NSString *textToShare = @"hello @[100003626828741]";
        NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                     @"picture":picture,
                                     @"name" : @"hello",
                                     @"caption" : textToShare,
                                     @"message" : textToShare,
                                     };
```

```
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                              URL:feedURL
                              parameters:parameters];

    feedRequest.account = [[ICollinaService instance] facebookAccount];

    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Facebook HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse
                                               statusCode]);
         NSLog(@"Facebook HTTP response allHeaderFields: %@", [urlResponse
                                               allHeaderFields]);
         NSLog(@"Facebook HTTP error: %@", error);
     }];

}
```

How can i mention a friend in my post? 
Thanks

The result of the post is: hello @[100003626828741] as a caption and message, without changeing the id for the name with link/tag.

Comment: doesn't work how? errors? crashes? posts to the wrong wall? insults the friend's mother?

Comment: Sorry, i just edit it. Thanks

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=post+tagging

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11464047/use-of-graph-api-to-post-a-feed-with-mentions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tag a friend in a post, but you can in an action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the Facebook Open Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/

I dont know if this is the best way to go!?!

I find it disturbing that its easy to pick friends with friendPicker and post pictures is extremely easy with IOS 6.0 social framework but to post the two combined with open Graph seems very difficult in comparison. Its however the only solution I have found so far.